# Is csound capable of pulling simple info/data from the Internet?

Tags: c++, c, csound

I am currently looking into using CSound for a project.

I want to receive data from an external source that is then used to manipulate a sound. So I am wondering... Is it possible for CSound to receive a data feed via the Internet?

This data would change a variable which then manipulates sounds.

The [sockrecv](http://www.csounds.com/manual/html/sockrecv.html/) function seems to be what could do this, but I am not sure what kind of data it accepts - anything? Just music? Or is there some other function that can do this?

Or could one just use something from C/C++?

Comment: If I recall correctly, this was discussed on the Csound mailing list, maybe it's possible with Csound6.

Answer (score 1):

Csound by itself doesn't offer this functionality in a simple way, but you could use the python or lua opcodes to run code within Csound. Or you could use Csound from the python (or other language) API and control things from there.